# how long should I set varbinary file length to fit documents

Tags: mysql

In a MySQL 5.6 database, I need to create a table that will store documents of variable length.  The documents will include PDF files, image files, even video files, etc.  Some documents will be small (as in two page pdf or a gif file), while others could be very large (as in textbook pdf or two hours of video).  Each document will be converted to a byte array in java prior to being inserted into the database.  The byte array will be mapped by hibernate to the content field in the documents table defined in the sql below.  What size setting should I use in defining the content field in the CREATE TABLE code below?

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
   id int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(100),
   description varchar(200),
   filename varchar(100),
   content VARBINARY(length?),
   contentType varchar(100), 
   created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
)
```

Comment: use a blob instead. then you're not limited to a fix number of characters, just the underlying size limit of the specific blob type.

Comment: @MarcB Thank you.  Someone told me that the current practice is to use byte arrays instead of blobs.  Is this true?  And can I insert a byte array from java/hibernate directly into a MySQL blob field?

Comment: I wouldn't store the files in a database - store them in the filesystem and store the metadata, including the file path, in the database.

Comment: mysql has absolutely NO concept of byte arrays. it just sees a string or a number or an opaque blob. it might be a byte array in java, but when it reaches mysql, it'll be a string/number/blob.

Comment: @MikeW Thank you. Wouldn't keeping the files in the file system require me to write a lot of code to lock down operations on the files in the file system from other applications? Like blocking renaming, relocating, or deleting of files by other applications?

Comment: @CodeMed if you have a lot of malicious, badly behaved apps and no user security, perhaps. Normally, just locating the files in a directory with appropriate permissions is enough. If you're in a web environment locate the files outside the web root and serve them with a simple script.

Comment: To expand upon @MikeW's previous comment, if you cannot rely upon your OS to protect the filesystem from undesirable modification, how can you have any certainty that MySQL's data and configuration files have also not been modified?

Comment: @MikeW I am more concerned about users who are not accustomed to working with files stored in a database.  Are you saying to make a copy of each file to store in a designated directory?  And then the users never work with that directory? Only my application uses that directory?

Comment: Yes `BLOB` would be the answer. Again, if you are going to store in DB rather in FS then I would suggest have a separate table for the Files and add document_id as `FK` for that table.

Comment: @CodeMed That's about it, but you're straying beyond the bounds of your original question. You haven't explained how users will be working with these files, how they will be uploading or downloading them, or what access controls you might need to implement. I suspect  that to do so will be too broad for [so] since that strays into system design rather than programming.